# React.Lazy usage throws "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to develop a simple application with two different components.
The main one uses `React.lazy` to get the other component and wraps it inside a `React.Suspense` element. But there is a super weird error in this simple example and a more abnormal hacky solution.

The error is:

> Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent

The source code is below. And I also created a [repository](https://github.com/Acanguven/TS2590-error) that you can easily repeat the error yourself.

**App.tsx contents**

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"

const Fr = React.lazy(
    () => import('./Fragment')
);

// Uncomment this line below, then it compiles without any errors
// const dummy = <Fr />

const Main = () => (
    <div>
        <React.Suspense fallback={"Loading"}>
            <div>
                <Fr/> {/* Error:  Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent */}
            </div>
        </React.Suspense>
    </div>
)

// @ts-ignore
ReactDom.render(<Main/>, document.body);
```

As you can see, `App.tsx` imports `./Fragment` with `React.lazy`. And when using the `Fr` component, Typescript throws the error.

**Fragment.tsx contents**

```
import * as React from "react"

const Fragment = () => (
    <div>
        Fragment
    </div>
)

export default Fragment
```

When using Typescript 4.1.2, it works without any error, but in 4.5.2, it is not.

**Weird Solution**

When you uncomment the dummy assignment `const dummy = <Fr />`, it works without any problem.

Now, I am wondering what is the actual problem here and why the dummy assignment solves it.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this issue and managed to fix it by updating the `compilerOptions.lib` option in the `tsconfig.json` file from `["ES2015"]` to `["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"]`.